# Cannot open gnome-control-center in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-control-center

I use the gnome desktop environment, and whenever I try to open the gnome control center I get an error saying:

```
[INFO 18:21:22.277197] Application.vala:153: System Settings version: 2.0
[INFO 18:21:22.277282] Application.vala:155: Kernel version: 4.10.0-30-generic
[FATAL 18:21:22.327817] [GLib] g_utf8_collate: assertion 'str1 != NULL' failed
[FATAL 18:21:22.328979] [GLib] g_utf8_collate: assertion 'str1 != NULL' failed
[FATAL 18:21:22.329407] [GLib] g_utf8_collate: assertion 'str1 != NULL' failed
[FATAL 18:21:22.330073] [GLib] g_utf8_collate: assertion 'str1 != NULL' failed
[FATAL 18:21:22.330846] [GLib] g_utf8_collate: assertion 'str1 != NULL' failed
[FATAL 18:21:22.331477] [GLib] g_utf8_collate: assertion 'str1 != NULL' failed
[ERROR 18:21:22.460428] [GLib-GIO] Settings schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.animations' is not installed
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: line 20:  9675 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) switchboard $switchboard_options $requested_plug
```

I have tried re installing gnome control center, but it hasn't worked. How do I solve the problem? Thankful for answers.

UPDATE:
this is the message from the command `cat /etc/default/locale`

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="sv_SE.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Show me the output of `cat /etc/default/locale`. Is this something that just started to fail for you? Do you have any other account on this system that you can log into and try this?

Comment: @heynnema This was the first time this problem occured.  I don't have any other account to log into and try this.  I have updated my question to show the output of the command.

Comment: So if you reboot, does the problem still occur?

Comment: @heynnema the problem is still there after I've rebooted

Comment: Temporarily disable all GNOME extensions, logout, log in, and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed some or all of enlightenment desktop.  No guarantees, but try this:

**WARNING: This could hose your system.**

```
sudo apt purge enlightenment-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
# and maybe
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

..this is the gist of what worked for me.  Use at your own risk.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either :(