# Cannot open system settings in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, settings

Recently I was unable to open Settings in Ubuntu 19.10 
I tried to reinstall gnome-control-center, but didn't work.
[I cannot open system settings in ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007378/i-cannot-open-system-settings-in-ubuntu-17-10) 

[It doesnt open the Users Settings, System Settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743511/it-doesnt-open-the-users-settings-system-settings) 
[Cannot open gnome-control-center in ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943611/cannot-open-gnome-control-center-in-ubuntu-17-04)
This is the output in terminal

When running in superuser

`# gnome-control-center
Bail out! ERROR:../shell/cc-shell-model.c:458:cc_shell_model_set_panel_visibility: assertion failed: (valid)`


When running in normal user

`$ gnome-control-center
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point: Permission denied
/dev/mem: Permission denied
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

**EDIT:** Working Solution - [Settings not opening on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183917/settings-not-opening-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: "*This it the output*" - knowing what command was executed might help us understand more clearly (and allow us to try the command on our boxes so we have a comparison of normal messages etc), but I get the sense that you've added packages for another release, or intended for another OS (thus ABI/API breakage & segfaults) , but it could also memory failure (which wouldn't be very consistent) & many other things.

Comment: @guiverc added the command. and btw, I installed xfce4. Is that the problem then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Settings not opening on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183917/settings-not-opening-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: @vanadium It has a part of the solution. It doesn't solve the 'Devices' section in settings issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution from this question:
[Settings not opening on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183917/settings-not-opening-on-ubuntu-19-10)

And it is to reset the last panel using this command:
`gsettings set org.gnome.ControlCenter last-panel ''`

and installing `hidpi-daemon` for Devices section in settings
`sudo apt install hidpi-daemon`

Comment: `hidpi-daemon` does not exist as a package in my fresh Ubuntu 19.10 install (main, univrse and multiverse enabled).

Comment: An update from the Pop!_OS PPA fixed this.
https://launchpad.net/~system76/+archive/ubuntu/pop